# ES7 Getting result from an array of promises using await generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony, ecmascript-2016

Given an array of promises, what's the idiomatic way to get the results in ES7?

Here's what I want to do:

```
async function getImports() {
  let imports = [System.import('./package1.js'), System.import('./package2.js')];
  let promises = await* imports;
  let results = [];
  await promises.forEach(val => val.then(data => results.push(data))); //seems hacky
  console.log(results); // array of 2 resolved imports
}
```

The result is correct, but I'm still doing a `forEach` and a `then` to turn the resolved promises into results. This just doesn't seem right to me. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Doesn't `promises` already contain the resolved values? At least that's what `let result = await* [Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)];` does for me?

Comment: Yep, each entry in `promises` contains a `[[PromiseValue]]`, but I don't know how to access them without the `forEach` and `then`

Comment: That's interesting. I just tried the above being transpiled by babel and it gave me the correct values. What do you use for transpiling?

Comment: im using babel 6. You're saying that `promises` returns the results & not promises?

Comment: The whole point of `async/await` is to not use promises manually anymore. It's hidden behind async functions and awaiting async functions.

Comment: I ran https://gist.github.com/m90/160f675da4d2abbf9685 in the Babel Repl: https://babeljs.io/repl - this is using Babel 5 though, so maybe something has changed here.

Comment: Thanks for the gist, so it looks like the return value is `[1,2]` but the `console.log` returns a promise still

Comment: I also tried and it [logs `[1, 2]`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=async%20function%20getResult()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20result%20%3D%20await*%20%5BPromise.resolve(1)%2C%20Promise.resolve(2)%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(result)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AgetResult()%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: hmmm, yup you're right it does log the result...wonder if its babel 6 then...

Comment: yep, definitely babel 6...

Comment: Created issue at https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T6866. Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: I'm trying to use babeljs to compile a simple js file and it's like trying to do voodoo magic: 'async function' is an unexpected token...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

As mentioned in the issue you filed, the core issue is that `await*` is no longer a thing and has been removed. Unfortunately, it was not properly throwing a syntax error in Babel 6 and was essentially being treated like a normal `await`.

You'll need to explicitly

```
 let [p1, p2] = await Promise.all([
          System.import('./package1.js'), System.import('./package2.js')]);
```

Comment: oh man, sorry to hear it won't be moving forward, but thank you for letting me know! If you have it handy, could you point me to a link on esdiscuss or where ever it was rejected? (this particular thing is hard to search for since no engine indexes `await*`)

Comment: The spec is always the best place to look. The proposed spec syntax is in https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait/blob/master/spec/syntax.html and only defines `await UnaryExpression`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Promise.each method from bluebird to make this code more expressive http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html There are still good reasons to use helper libs like Bluebird even with ES7 async await

Answer (score 1):

I cannot believe it actually works, `forEach` does return `undefined` which you cannot `await`. If you need a loop, use `map` to get an array of (promised) results.

In your case, you seem to be looking for a simple

```
async function getImports() {
  let promises = [System.import('./package1.js'), System.import('./package2.js')];
  let results = await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log(results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it this ....

```
async function abc() {
    let p1 = getReviews();
    let p2 = getMenu();
    let [reviews, menu] = await results(p1, p2);
}

function results(...rest) {
    return Promise.all(rest).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```