# node.js async/await using with MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I need to get all results synchronized and append to a  string with async/await keywords like c#.

I am new to node.js and I can not adapt this new syntax to my code.

```
var string1 = '';
var string2 = '';
var string3 = '';
var string4 = '';

DatabasePool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

        connection.query(query,function (err, result) {
            if (err){};
            string1 = result;
        });

        connection.query(query,function (err, result) {
            if (err){};
            string2 = result;
        });     

        connection.query(query,function (err, result) {
            if (err){};
            string3 = result;   
        });

        connection.query(query,function (err, result) {
            if (err){};
            string4 = result;
        }); 

       //I need to append all these strings to appended_text but  
       //all variables remain blank because below code runs first.
       var appended_text = string1 + string2 + string3 + string4;
});
```

Comment: Just checking, you are using a version of node that supports async/await, correct?

Comment: yes the latest version.

Answer (score 100):

if you happen to be in Node **8+**, you can leverage the native `util.promisify()` with the node mysql.

Do not forget to call it with `bind()` so the `this` will not mess up:

```
const mysql = require('mysql'); // or use import if you use TS
const util = require('util');
const conn = mysql.createConnection({yourHOST/USER/PW/DB});

// node native promisify
const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

(async () => {
  try {
    const rows = await query('select count(*) as count from file_managed');
    console.log(rows);
  } finally {
    conn.end();
  }
})()
```

Comment: Thanks for the note on adding bind. I've spent way too long try to work out why I've been having issues with promisify.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint on the correct way of doing the bind

Comment: If i have to provide 2 arguments to query function, typescript giving error "expected 1 argument". I am using two arguments because query string contains a `?`. Is there a way to avoid appending second argument in single query string?

Comment: For typescript:


const query: (arg1: string, arg2?: string[])=>Promise<unknown> = promisify(db.query).bind(db);

Comment: The mysql-async-simple package does that for you.

Comment: @AmitKumar, for TS, instead of passing queryString, you can also use the `QueryOptions` as the 1st argument, which contains `sql`,`values` and other options.

Comment: Do not use `mysql` anymore, it's not updated anymore. Please use `mysql2` now.

Answer (score 75):

Use mysql2 packet. It has promise wrapper so you can do that:

```
async function example1 () {
  const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
  const conn = await mysql.createConnection({ database: test });
  let [rows, fields] = await conn.execute('select ?+? as sum', [2, 2]);
}
```

Comment: This is the superior answer... Holy cow Mysql2 is *MUCH FASTER* than mysql, and offers tons of stuff mysql does not, like promises and compression and prepared statements.

Comment: dont forget to end connection after executing query with  await conn.end(); or better use pool instead of connections like createPool and ending pool.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as mysql is now deprecated, mysql2 is still maintained to this day and supports async

Comment: I am a little confused here, do I need to create a connection to MySQL with each query or make conn as global and use in all routes?

Comment: `https://npmcompare.com/compare/mysql,mysql2` --> `mysql2` is a better package, also it has  more meaning full error messages which this comparison won't tell

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that your ORM that you are using it promise-based you can do something like this

```
async function buildString() {
  try {
    const connection = await DatabasePool.getConnection();
    const string1 = await connection.query(query);
    const string2 = await connection.query(query);
    const string3 = await connection.query(query);
    const string4 = await connection.query(query);

    return string1 + string2 + string3 + string4;
  } catch (err) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Any promise can be used with async/await by putting `await` in front of the call. However, notice that *this* function must be used within an `async` function "wrapper". You need to handle the errors in `try/catch` blocks.

I also want to point out that these 4 queries are **not** run simulatneously. You'll still need to use Promise.all for that.

Comment: Be aware that await can only be used within async methods.

Comment: Thanks @WilcoBakker. I was actually just editing my answer :)

Comment: I use mysql package.I think this is not promise-based?Which mysql package should i use ?

Comment: There are quite a few so I think you may want to take some time to explore the tradeoffs. Some that you may come across are: objection.js, bookshelf, sequelize

Comment: how can i get the returned row values from the queries instead of getting strings?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use mysql (also called mysqljs) you have to do a little bit of work if you don't want to use a wrapper. But it's easy enough. Here is how the connect function would look like:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')

var my_connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... })

async function connect()
{
    try
    {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            my_connection.connect(err => {
                return err ? reject(err) : resolve()
            })
        })
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        ...handle errors...
    }
}

connect()
```

As you can see the await will know how to handle a promise. You create such and use the resolve/reject functions in the callback implementation. That's all there is to it, really, so using a wrapper may be a bit much unless you access your database a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Or use mysql-async-simple

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-async-simple

```html
const { makeDb } = require('mysql-async-simple');
const mysql = require("mysql");
 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB
});
const db = makeDb();
await db.connect(connection);
 
try {
    const users = await db.query(connection, 'SELECT * FROM users');
} catch (e) {
    // handle exception
} finally {
    await db.close(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As stated by [LeOn - Han Li](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690276/5503272), i include small modifications, since I had to work with the result.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
const util = require('util');

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '127.0.0.1',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});

const query = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(conn);

let result = async function() {
    var userCourse = [];
    try {
        const rows = await query('select * as count from file_managed');
    } finally {
        conn.end();
        return userCourse;
    }
};

result()
.then(value => {
    console.log(value)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`promise-mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql) package like so:

```js
const mysql = require('promise-mysql')

const getDbConnection = async () => {
  return await mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB
  })
}

const getUsers = async () => {
  const db = await getDbConnection()
  const users = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users")
  await db.end()
  return users
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make sure that the mysql library you are using either supports Promises, which are required by `async`/`await`, or use a tool like [Bluebird's `promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) to wrap the library.

```
async function appendedText() {
  const connection = await DatabasePool.getConnectionAsync();
  const [string1, string2, string3, string4] = await [
    connection.query(query1),
    connection.query(query2),
    connection.query(query3),
    connection.query(query4),
  ];
  return string1 + string2 + string3 + string4;
}
```

Note that calling `appendedText()` will actually return a Promise and not a value.

```
appendedText().then(appended_text => {});
```

Comment: Can you really use await like that to mimic Promise.all? Any idea where I can find more information on that because my quick googling has returned very complex methods.

Comment: @adam-beck, it was working for a while... it requires a `Promise.all()` now, though. See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382710/es7-getting-result-from-an-array-of-promises-using-await-generator#answer-34384344

Answer (score 1):

```html
const { makeDb } = require('mysql-async-simple');
const mysql = require("mysql");
 
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.HOST,
    user: process.env.USER,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB
});
const db = makeDb();
await db.connect(connection);
 
try {
    const users = await db.query(connection, 'SELECT * FROM users');
} catch (e) {
    // handle exception
} finally {
    await db.close(connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use [mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) which isn't a promised based library. So you can't achieve what you want using this library. So what you can do is use a promised based library like [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) or else as a comment suggests:

> use a tool like Bluebird's promisifyAll to wrap the library.

I don't know much about wrapping thing, so what I did was to switch to the sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **util** or **promise/mysql** we can implement promise inside **mysql.connect**

var con = require('mysql');

```
var mysql = con.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "pass",
    database: "test"
});

async function asyncAwait(req, res) {
    var promise1;
    mysql.connect((err) => {
        promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log('Mysql: Connected');
            resolve(response.write(uc.upperCase('Connected\n')));
        });
        promise1
            .then(() => {
             //Implement the logic here
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    })
}
await asyncAwait();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had to create a helper function which is a promise and resolves as follows

```
const mysqlQuery = async (connection, queryConfig) => {
    const config = { ...queryConfig, timeout: 4000 }

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     return connection.query(config, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
        resolve(results);
      });
   })
}
```

Now i can easily use the above like

```
    const response = await mysqlQuery(connection, {
       sql: 'SELECT * FROM `user`',
    });

     console.log(response)
```

where connection is you mysql connection as like below

```
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host,
        user, //
        password, //
        database,
        port
    })
   
    connection.connect(async (err) => {
          if(err){
             //connection error
             return;
           }

         //successifull connection
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following mysql2:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

so it still does not work with the aforementioned code above.  I'll try sequelize and see if that works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35687916)