# Give value outside of callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, express

```
function doesUserExist(email){
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email = "${email}"`
    var x = false;


    let exists = connection.query(sql,(error,results,fields)=>{
        if(error) throw error;
        
        if(results === undefined || results.length === 0) x = false;
        else x = true;
    });

    return x;
}
```

How can I return a value out of callback or is there some other pattern I can use to accomplish same thing? It seems `x` never gets updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js async/await using with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004418/node-js-async-await-using-with-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to consume the value elsewhere, the best method is to return a promise containing the initial query, then consume it with an async function. If not, you're pretty much stuck doing all the work inside the callback.

Here's a away to consume a promise with async/await:

```
function doesUserExist(email){
  let sql = `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE email = "${email}"`

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     connection.query(sql,(error,results,fields)=>{
        if (error) reject(error);
        resolve(results);
     });
  }
 }
```

Then you could consume it with an async function like so:

```
async function consumeValue() {
  let results = await doesUserExist(email);

  console.log(results);
  // Do something with results.
}
```

Comment: This is why it's so hard to learn javascript.. it's such an odd creature. Thank you.

Comment: @sander Actually, I misunderstood the question and gave a poor answer. I'm editing now for a proper solution.

Comment: Updated code works like a charm, thanks! Kind of difficult to know when to use Promises and when not.. but I guess that'll come clearer over time.