# Node.js mysql Module Wait for Query Results

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to do something that should be very straightforward.  I need to wait for mysql query results so that they can be returned as an HTTP response.  However, the only examples I can find simply write query results to the console and do not wait for results.

I've tried many approaches given online for generic wait/promise.  Here's the latest one I tried using util.promisify() from this post; [node.js async/await using with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004418/node-js-async-await-using-with-mysql)

Here is my sample code;

```
function callbackQuery(error: any, results: any, field: any) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);

      return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'There was an error' }),
      };
    } else {
      console.log(results);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'There was NO error' }),
      };
    }
  }

  function queryWrapper() {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM my_table', callbackQuery);
  }

  const myQuery = util.promisify(queryWrapper).bind(connection);

  (async () => {
    try {
      const res = await myQuery();
      console.log(res);

      return res;
    } finally {
      connection.end();
    }
  })();
```

And here are the results;

> Request from ::ffff:127.0.0.1: GET
> /.netlify/functions/ ◈ lambda response was undefined.
> check your function code again Response with status 500
> in 100 ms.[ RowDataPacket {   } ]

So, essentially, no waiting is happening because the 'lambda response was undefined' is output before the query result set.  I would expect the response, 'There was NO error' instead.  Does anyone have a simple example of how to wait for the data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004418/node-js-async-await-using-with-mysql

Comment: @hoangdv Not sure what this comment means because I included this link in my question.  Are you saying I implemented the proposed solution incorrectly?

Comment: I'm sorry, i mean just follow the answer in the question, try to make it work at first.

Comment: queryWrapper isn't returning anything. I wrote a doc specifically when seeing so many people struggle with mysql in node. Hope it helps: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/