# Modify HTML from NodeJS mySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am new to NodeJS and MySQL, so I am trying this: I have created a table which is connected with nodejs. I succesfuly managed to console log an item that I wanted. I have also started a localhost server on port 3000 where I managed to add an h1 element to the html. However, I can't seem to find a add the result in the h1. In this case I have a random word in my database which I want to be displayed as H1.

JS:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host: "*****",
user: "root",
password: "*****",
database: "mydb"
});

var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs');  

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(result[1].name);
    })
  });
  
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;  
    switch (path) {  
      case '/':  
      response.writeHead(200, {  
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'  
      });  
      response.write("This is a Test Message.");  
      response.end();  
      break;  
      case '/index.html':  
      fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
        if (error) {  
          response.writeHead(404);  
          response.write(error);  
          response.end();  
        } else {  
          response.writeHead(200, {  
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
          });
          response.write(data);
          response.write("<html>")
          response.write("<h1>Added this with NodeJS!</h1>")
          response.write("</html>")
          response.end();  
        }  
      });  
      break;  
      default:  
      response.writeHead(404);  
      response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");  
      response.end();  
      break;  
    }  
});  

  server.listen(3000);
```

I tried to add the result this way, but it didn't work. I got an error saying that result is not defined.

```
          response.write("<html>")
          response.write("<h1>")
          response.write("His name is:" + result[1].name)
          response.write("</h1>")
          response.write("</html>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `result` is not available in the scope you are trying to use it in, hence you get an error saying it's undefined.

`result` should be available in the scope you are trying to use it in that is your request handler (the top function). You can do so by declaring it in the handlers' scope. This is an example, you can use a different name of course:

```
let data;

// inside the query callback
data = result
```

However, this solution makes error handling hard.

Try using promises instead with `then()` or `async` / `await` along with `catch()`:

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51690276/13864427), or use `mysql2` package if you can.

Comment: However, in the original code, the http response would likely be written before the results were retrieved, so it is better to more formally nest / promise / await  on the callback.

Comment: @BluntJackson thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

result is a variable defined in the query callback function:

```
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(result[1].name);
  })
});
```

It doesn't exist OUTSIDE that callback, even though to the untrained eye it might seem like it should.

There are many different ways to get the data where you need it such as using promises to resolve your sql query when it has completed, and use the result to populate your http response. But a quick and dirty way is to just shove your http response in that callback:

```
var http = require('http');  
var url = require('url');  
var fs = require('fs');  

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(result[1].name);
      var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;  
      switch (path) {  
        case '/':  
          response.writeHead(200, {  
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'  
          });  
          response.write("This is a Test Message.");  
          response.end();  
          break;  
        case '/index.html':  
          fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data) {  
            if (error) {  
              response.writeHead(404);  
              response.write(error);  
              response.end();  
            } else {  
              response.writeHead(200, {  
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
              });
              response.write(data);
              response.write("<html>")
              response.write(`<h1>${response[1].name}</h1>`)
              response.write("</html>")
              response.end();  
            }  
          });  
          break;  
        default:  
          response.writeHead(404);  
          response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");  
          response.end();  
          break;  
      }  
    });
  });
});  

server.listen(3000);
```

To be clear: this is not the "right" way to do this, and definitely not an elegant way. It is a proof of concept.