# trying to get the resultId back from an insert in react.js using mysql2/promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, insert, mysql2

I am trying to get the resultId back when using mysql2/promise, but it won't allow be to do a

```
callback on the connection.query line, so I have to use:
      (async () => {
            try {
                                 //connection.query(config, function (error, results, fields) {
              const rows = await connection.query(sql);
              //console.log("results to resultId is:" + results.resultId);
              console.log(rows);
            } finally {
              
              //connection.end();
            }
          })()
```

here is my require section:

```
const PORT = 8000;
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
```

and my connection to database:

```
  async function getConnection() {
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'thepasswordforexample',
        database: 'databasename',
    });
    return connection;
  }
```

I can run the query, but I don't get the resultId back. How do I fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I already looked through:
[node.js async/await using with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004418/node-js-async-await-using-with-mysql/78037503#78037503)
and none of those solutions work.

Thanks in advance, and please bear with me as I am learning this new language.

Comment: so the following works: (async () => {
            try {                       
              const rows = await connection.query(sql).then(function(data) {
                console.log("data is" + JSON.stringify(data));
                console.log("insertid is:" + data.insertId);
                //res.send(" ");
              });
              console.log(rows);
            } finally {
            }
          })()  //now I just need insertId from data.. that part is not working....

Comment: finally got it:   console.log("data[0].insertId is: " + data[0].insertId);